# How to return integer in ruby main method

Tags: ruby

Here is my code

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  puts "tests"
  puts $PROGRAM_NAME
  return 1
end
```

I am trying to have a git pre-commit feature with ruby. And this pre-commit needs an integer return.

When I run this piece ruby code I got an error

```
`<main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
```

Comment: @minitech I believe that's right if memory serves me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@minitech says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168854/how-to-return-integer-in-ruby-main-method#comment17919340_13168854), you want to use [`exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit).

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  puts "tests"
  puts $PROGRAM_NAME
  exit 1
end
```

Comment: *Usually*, `0` is success and `1` is failure in regards to exit codes. I don't know if Ruby changes them, though.